# facing problems with password form in c#

Tags: c#, forms, passwords

i have two different forms with one form dedicated to password input and if the password is correct open a dialog box for loading file from pc and if wrong a message box appears stating wrong password. 
the problem with this is if the program is started and i clicked the button and enter the correct password and succesfully loaded the file. but if again i press the button to enter the password and i close the popup manually by X on the top, i get access to the dialog box window. i am unable to get how to stop this.

my codes are as follows

form 1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        formpopup popup = new formpopup();
        popup.ShowDialog();
        if (formpopup.j == 1)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openfiledialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openfiledialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

another form of password is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class formpopup : Form
{
    public formpopup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public static int j = 0;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = textBox1.Text;
        if (a == "1234")
        {
            j = 1;
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
            this.Close();

        }
        else
        {
            j = 0;
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
            this.Close();


        }
    }

   private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

yes i also tried to used form.Dispose() command but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solution want *redesigning*: what on Earth `"j"` means?

```
// Make the class name readable, use upper case (FormPopup instead of formpopup):
public partial class FormPopup : Form {
  public FormPopup() {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  //TODO: rename the button as well as the textbox 
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (textBox1.Text == "1234") 
      DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
    else
      DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;

    // In case form was open as non-dialog
    Close();
  } 
}

....

public partial class Form1 : Form {
  ...
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Wrap IDisposable into using
    using (FormPopup dialog = new FormPopup()) {
      if (dialog.ShowDialog() != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) 
        return; // wrong password
    }

    // Wrap IDisposable into using
    using (OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog()) {
      if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
        //TODO: put relevant code here
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. "j" actually it is the first character of my name, so used it in a general way for testing.           2. it is giving me an error at "if (dialog.ShowDialog != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) "     error is: "Error 1 Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult' ".

Comment: @JITIN MALHOTRA: Sorry for typo, it should be `dialog.ShowDialog()` not  `dialog.ShowDialog`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your **j** is static. Make it non-static, so it would refer to an instance of your form

```
public int j = 0;
```

And then you should refer to your form in the way something like that

```
    if (popup.j == 1)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openfiledialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openfiledialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: if i don't use static it give me an error, " An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'WindowsFormsApplication2.formpopup.j' "

Comment: don't use `formpopup.j` , use `popup.j`. You should refer to the object, not class.

Comment: "formpopup" is name of my class having the windows form

Comment: I know it. If you you use static field, the changes you've made would stay through the button's click. The second time, you click on button1, your `j` is already 1. When you use non-static field, your `j` would be set to 0 in every initialization of `popup`

Comment: but if i don't use static it gives me an error as commented by me above

Comment: You receives error because you are trying to refer to the class(`formpopup.j`). You shoud use `popup.j` in your code, not the `formpopup.j`